# why does simple_html_dom find('tr')[0] get table row 2 instead of table row 1?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

why does find('tr')[0]; get table row 2 instead of table row 1 ?

This is my html all tables have the same class and layout.

```
<table class="tablemenu">
   <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><b>hello</b></td>
          <td><b>hi</b></td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>hey</td>
          <td>Alright</td>
          <td>Good</td>
          <td>Good</td>
          <td><a>Date</a></td>  
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<table class="tablemenu">
   <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><b>hello</b></td>
          <td><b>hi</b></td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>hey</td>
          <td>Alright</td>
          <td>Good</td>
          <td>Good</td>
          <td><a>Date</a></td>  
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<table class="tablemenu">
   <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><b>hello</b></td>
          <td><a>hi</a></td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>hey</td>
          <td>Alright</td>
          <td>Good</td>
          <td>Good</td>
          <td><a>LINK</a></td>  
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my php

```
<?php

include("simpleHtmlDom/simple_html_dom.php");

$html = new simple_html_dom();

// Load a file 
$html->load_file('http://mySite.net/');

foreach($html->find('table[class=tablemenu]') as $element){

 $Link = $element->find('tr')[0]->find('td')[4]->find('a')[0];        

  echo($Link->text());             
  echo '<br />'; 

}

?>
```

At first to get the word 'Date' i tried

```
$Link = $element->find('tr')[1]->find('td')[4]->find('a')[0];
```

But that didn't work, it said undefined index.

Then i tried this just messing around and it works

```
$Link = $element->find('tr')[0]->find('td')[4]->find('a')[0];
```

This gets the word Date for some reason. I don't understand why, i do need that but
although it works - i now can't access table row 1. to grab the word say  "hi".

Comment: you dont have 4 td in tr[0]

Comment: If you were using an IDE like Netbeans it would highlight this kind of mistakes and you wouldn't lose that much time asking about it on SO.

Comment: I have an IDE Nusphere phpED, it highlights the left bracket of the zero on $element->find('tr')[0]-> but thats it

Comment: sorry i just quickly typed this in, there is 5 <td>s in my code and my tr are closed properly i will edit it in my Question now

Comment: Do have have any ideas now ?

Answer (score 1):

I see <strike>two</strike> one issue<strike>s</strike>:

Your first `<tr>` only has 2 `<td>`s, so `$element->find('tr')[0]->find('td')[4]` should throw an exception.

***Edit** OP fixed pasted code.*

<strike>Fix your markup. You're not properly closing your `<tr>` elements:</strike>

```
<table class="tablemenu">
   <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><b>hello</b></td>
          <td><b>hi</b></td>  
        </tr> <!-- close this! --->
        <tr>
          <td>hey</td>
          <td>Alright</td>
          <td>Good</td>
          <td><a>Date</a></td>  
        </tr> <!-- close this! --->
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: sorry i just quickly typed this in, there is 5 <td>s in my code and my tr are closed properly i will edit it in my Question now

Comment: Do have have any ideas now ?

Comment: i know, but it dosent it gets "date", im wondering why that is.

Comment: Because "date" is in your second `<tr>` and your statement (`$element->find('tr')[0]`) selects only the first `<tr>`.

Comment: $element->find('tr')[0]) "IS" PRINTING DATE, I WOULD LIKE TO KNOW WHY

Comment: There isn't enough context given in the code you've provided to answer that question. If you can reproduce the issue someplace you can share (such as http://codepad.viper-7.com/) that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is `wrong indexing` because you are not closing the `tr tags` properly

the link should be on **first index instead of zeroth index**

```
$Link = $element->find('tr')[1]->find('td')[4]->find('a')[0];
```

To `print` **hi**  try

```
echo $element->find('tr')[0]->find('td')[1]->find('b')[0]->text();
```

**Full code**

```
foreach($html->find('table[class=tablemenu]') as $element){
   $Link = $element->find('tr')[1]->find('td')[4]->find('a')[0];        
   echo($Link->text());             
   echo '<br />'; 
   echo $element->find('tr')[0]->find('td')[1]->find('b')[0]->text();  
}
```

If the above not works then find `tr` in `tbody` like

```
$Link = $element->find('tbody')->find('tr')[1]->find('td')[4]->find('a')[0];
```

Also for **debugging**, try this

```
foreach($html->find('table[class=tablemenu]') as $element){
   echo '<pre>';
   var_dump($element);// find the object here
   echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: sorry i just quickly typed this in, there is 5 <td>s in my code and my tr are closed properly i will edit it in my Question now

Comment: Do have have any ideas now ?

Comment: i tried "  $Link = $element->find('tbody')->find('tr')[1]->find('td')[4]->find('a')[0];  " but i throws an error Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in

Comment: And what about `debugging option`?

Comment: Im looking through it, its making me dizzy trying to find the tags, will let you know, ive been using firebug for this, is that a bad idea ?